# How to implement resizable div with fixed increments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a vertical resizable div such that it increases height in certain fixed intervals. I don't want to use any libraries and looking for plain JS implementation. Here is jquery version: https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#snap-to-grid

This code works good but increases height by one pixel on each mousemove (vertically). 
When I try to increase height by 10, the height increases but the mouse pointer does not stick to the base of div..,

https://plnkr.co/edit/3VesixHE2B7N46f8N7Bg?p=preview

```js
const divElement = document.querySelector('.ns-resize');
const element = document.querySelector('.resizable');
let original_height = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', ''));
let original_Y =  element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
divElement.onmousedown = function(mouseDownEvent) {
    mouseDownEvent.preventDefault();
    var original_mouse_y = mouseDownEvent.pageY;
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);
    function resize(mouseUpEvent) {
        //cmp.increment = cmp.increment + 15; 
        const height = original_height + (mouseUpEvent.pageY - original_mouse_y); 
        if (height > 15 && height < 900) {
            mouseUpEvent.pageY = mouseUpEvent.pageY ; 
            element.style.height = height + 'px';
            divElement.innerHTML = element.style.height;
            
        }
    }

    function stopResize() {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize)
      }

    
}
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.resizable  {
    width: 100px; 
    height : 100px;
    border:1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
   
}
.container {
    position : relative;
}

.ns-resize {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    cursor: ns-resize;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body> 
        <div class="resizable">
            <div class="ns-resize">
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
         </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

}

I could increase height by one pixel on every mousemove event, but what I really want is to increase by 10px each time.

Comment: I would just use the css rule: `resize: vertical;` so you can drag the bottom of the div and then use a onmouseup event to change the height of the div to the nearest 10px of it's current height.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in my comment, CSS already has a resize property you can use to make an element resizable. The only thing you need to do after a resize, is round the current height to the nearest 10px.

```js
document.querySelector( '.resizable' ).addEventListener( 'mouseup', event => {
  const current_height = parseInt( event.target.style.height, 10 );
  event.target.style.height = Math.round( current_height / 10 ) * 10 + 'px';
  console.log( `changed height from ${ current_height }px to ${ event.target.style.height }` );
});
```

```css
.resizable {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: vertical;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="resizable"></div>
```

Only mighty want to add a check now to not run the function when something else inside the div is clicked.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for pure JS solution as css resize property is not supported in IE11.

Comment: Actually, I figured it. Instead of increasing the height everytime by height = height + 10, I changed the logic to increase only when height%10 == 0